# Get iterable of values from dictionary with iterable of keys

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, dictionary

I have an numpy array (which can be a list) with the keys of a dictionary. I need to get all the values in a the dictionary where the keys matches the array values as fast as possible. I currently do that with a comprehensive list:

```
original_list = [1, 3, 4]
my_dict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
np_list = np.array(original_list)
np_values = np.array([my_dict[key] for key in np_list])
```

Is there a way to make this faster?

Comment: You can only index a `dict` with one key at a time, so in general you have work as you've done.  In some cases you can replace the dict with two lists, keys and values, and select things fasater that way.  Here, for example, the keys are consecutive integers, so array indexing would be faster:  `np.array([' ','a','b','c','d'])[np_list]`

Comment: Yes, dont iterate over the numpy array, iterate over the list. But it will still fundamentally be a linear time algorithm

Comment: @hpaulj I tried that with numba using njit (with previous sorting those lists) and got 3x worst performance (without counting the sort). Maybe numpy has a solution but I haven't figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Let's explore some alternatives:

```
In [35]: original_list = [1, 3, 4] 
    ...: my_dict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

A straight forward list comprehension - pure python:

```
In [36]: [my_dict[key] for key in original_list]                                
Out[36]: ['a', 'c', 'd']
In [37]: timeit [my_dict[key] for key in original_list]                         
441 ns ± 1.33 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

For this converting the list to array does not help.  Iteration on an array is slower than on an equivalent list.  It may even be worth doing a `arr.tolist()` prior to iteration.

```
In [38]: np_list = np.array(original_list)                                      
In [39]: timeit [my_dict[key] for key in np_list]                               
2.68 µs ± 59.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

converting the resulting list to array also takes time:

```
In [40]: timeit np.array([my_dict[key] for key in np_list])                     
7.05 µs ± 34.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

In a comment I suggested extracting the keys and values from the dict:

```
In [41]: list(my_dict.keys())                                                   
Out[41]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
In [42]: list(my_dict.values())                                                 
Out[42]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

With these keys we can construct a 'keyed' array:

```
In [43]: arr = np.array(['_']+_)                                                
In [44]: arr                                                                    
Out[44]: array(['_', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='<U1')
In [45]: arr[np_list]                                                           
Out[45]: array(['a', 'c', 'd'], dtype='<U1')
```

Array indexing is quite fast:

```
In [46]: timeit arr[np_list]                                                    
283 ns ± 12.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

For larger lists/dicts/arrays the array indexing should do even better.

Another little trick - a generator expression and `fromiter`:

```
In [48]: timeit np.fromiter((my_dict[key] for key in original_list), dtype='U1')                                                                       
2.84 µs ± 45.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is O(n), there is no approach with better time complexity than O(n), so the answer to your question is no.

Comment: Generally 'O' complexity doesn't help with high level code that mixes interpreted and compiled operations.  O(n) in compiled code is virtually O(1) in interpreted, and so on.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm going to have to disagree. O(N) is O(N). The whole point of complexity analysis is to ignore constant factors.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I came across with `itemgetter` from `operator` which showed very good performance against the comprehensive list approach

```
a = list(itemgetter(*searched_keys)(my_dict))
```

Performance sum up:

- `itemgetter` was generally faster
- `itemgetter` time did not scale with dictionary size, but it increased with searched keys amount linearly.
- Comprehensive list approach time scaled linearly with dictionary size, but it did not scaled with searched keys amount.

Test and results (100, 1000, 10000 keys) get 20 values:

```
import timeit
setup = '''
import random
from operator import itemgetter
my_dict = {i: random.randint(0, 10000)/5.42 for i in range({0})}
searched_keys = set()
while len(searched_keys) < {1}:
    searched_keys.add(random.choice(list(my_dict.keys())))'''
test_cl_if = '''
a = [v for k, v in my_dict.items() if k in searched_keys]
'''
test_cl_call = '''
a = [my_dict[k] for k in searched_keys]
'''
test_ig = '''
a = list(itemgetter(*searched_keys)(my_dict))
'''
print('Comprehensive list if:')
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(100)).replace('{1}', str(20)), stmt=test_cl_if, number=100), 5))
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(1000)).replace('{1}', str(20)), stmt=test_cl_if, number=100), 5))
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(10000)).replace('{1}', str(20)), stmt=test_cl_if, number=100), 5))
print('\nComprehensive list call:')
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(100)).replace('{1}', str(20)), stmt=test_cl_if, number=100), 5))
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(1000)).replace('{1}', str(20)), stmt=test_cl_if, number=100), 5))
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(10000)).replace('{1}', str(20)), stmt=test_cl_if, number=100), 5))
print('\nitemgetter:')
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(100)).replace('{1}', str(20)), stmt=test_ig, number=100), 5))
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(1000)).replace('{1}', str(20)), stmt=test_ig, number=100), 5))
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(10000)).replace('{1}', str(20)), stmt=test_ig, number=100), 5))
```

Output:

```
Comprehensive list if:
0.00054
0.00466
0.04597

Comprehensive list call:
0.00053
0.00458
0.0452

itemgetter:
0.00014
0.00014
0.00014
```

Test and results 10000 keys get (20, 200, 2000) values:

```
...
print('Comprehensive list if:')
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(10000)).replace('{1}', str(20)), stmt=test_cl_if, number=100), 5))
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(10000)).replace('{1}', str(200)), stmt=test_cl_if, number=100), 5))
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(10000)).replace('{1}', str(2000)), stmt=test_cl_if, number=100), 5))
print('\nComprehensive list call:')
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(10000)).replace('{1}', str(20)), stmt=test_cl_if, number=100), 5))
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(10000)).replace('{1}', str(200)), stmt=test_cl_if, number=100), 5))
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(10000)).replace('{1}', str(2000)), stmt=test_cl_if, number=100), 5))
print('\nitemgetter:')
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(10000)).replace('{1}', str(20)), stmt=test_ig, number=100), 5))
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(10000)).replace('{1}', str(200)), stmt=test_ig, number=100), 5))
print(round(timeit.timeit(setup=setup.replace('{0}', str(10000)).replace('{1}', str(2000)), stmt=test_ig, number=100), 5))
```

Output:

```
Comprehensive list if:
0.04446
0.04782
0.05263

Comprehensive list call:
0.04444
0.04774
0.05515

itemgetter:
0.00015
0.00107
0.01101
```